# Migrate to Magento 2.0 - How can I Ignore the theme

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.0 and I dont want to migrate the custom theme that I already having in 1.9.1.0.

Is there a way I can configure to ignore the theme while migrating the data?

Comment: Why do you believe it is migrating the theme?  I did not think the theme would have been migrated since it is not data in the database, and themes are not compatible between M1 and M2.

Comment: after migration in `core_config_data` i got all settings realted to Magento 1 theme, is there any way to ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as migrating from Magento 1.x to Magento 2. They are both completely different platforms. You can migrate the database with a tool, but the entire codebase needs to be rebuild. All extensions, themes, customisations, etc.

So in my opinion, you should just migrate the database and start from scratch in Magento and set and develop the correct theme in Magento 2.

Comment: after migration in `core_config_data` i got all settings related to Magento 1 theme, is there any way to ignore it

Comment: You probably can, but I'm not sure if you can ignore specific configuration settings. My suggestion would be to copy them and then manually update them in Magento 2, so you can change them to the correct settings right away.